# Microsoft Graph Rest API: How to get MIME-Content from an ItemAttachment in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

how can I get the MIME-Content from an ItemAttachment (Message) attached to an email in C#?

In the Graph Explorer it is possible to get the MIME-Content:

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid%7D/messages/%7Bid%7D/attachments/%7Bid%7D/$value)

The Graph Explorer suggests to use ".Content" in C#. But if I try this, the compiler says:

> Error CS1061  'IAttachmentRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition
> for 'Content' and no accessible extension method 'Content' accepting a
> first argument of type 'IAttachmentRequestBuilder' could be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

C# code:

```
private async Task<ItemAttachment> GetItemAttachment(string id)
{
    ItemAttachment itemAttachment = null;

    var attachment = await GraphServiceClient
        .Users[CurrentUser.Id]
        .Messages[CurrentMessage.Id]
        .Attachments[id]
        .Content
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();

    itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;

    return itemAttachment;
}
```

What is the correct way to get the MIME-content of an attachment in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content` property is missing for C#. I don't know the reason.

As an alternative you can try send the http request and read the content from the response.

```
// create request url
var requestUrl = GraphServiceClient.Users[CurrentUser.Id].Messages[CurrentMessage.Id]
   .Attachments[id].AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("$value");
// create request
var hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
// authenticate request
await client.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);
// send request and read response
var response = await client.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
// read content
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```